# css menu code not working

Tags: css, jsf, facelets

I tried creating a css menu in an Facelets page put it seems my div class is not been recognized.here is the code

Facelets page

```
 <h:form>
 <div class=“menu“>
  <ul> 
  <li><a href=“#“> create staff </li>
   <li><a href=“#“> view staff </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</h:form>
```

My css menu code is fine but when I save and deploy the application on netbeans it doesn't effect any change. Been wondering if the `<h:` tags for styleClass could be needed for it to work on a JSF/Facelets page. Any help?

Comment: Use the style inspector in Firefox or similar to see (a) whether the styles you believe are being applied are actually being applied, and (b) whether the styles contain the rules you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Curly quotes `“` are syntactically [invalid](http://validator.w3.org) in this context.

Use straight quotes `"` instead. On [US international keyboards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#US-International), it's the 2nd key on the right side from the <kbd>L</kbd> key, right before the <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Don't forget to press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

```
 <h:form>
 <div class="menu">
  <ul> 
  <li><a href="#"> create staff </li>
   <li><a href="#"> view staff </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</h:form>
```

Do not write/copypaste HTML in MS Word/Outlook/etc applications. Do it in a real HTML editor.